# How to uninstall pipewire and go back to pulseaudio

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, pipewire

I am using `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version (Jammy Jellyfish)`. I was facing a slight glitch while using my bluetooth headset mic. So, I tried to switch to pipewire to check if it solves my problem. But after switching I see my inbuilt speakers also doesnot work. I need to go back to `default configuration` of Ubuntu 22.04. The exact steps that I followed to go the pipewire were this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pipewire
sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse
systemctl --user mask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service
```

Now every time I start the computer I need to run these commands to get things working again:

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

I do not want to do this again and again how can I go roll back all these changes

Comment: Basically `pulseaudio` is not autostarting for my current user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following commands helped me:

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire-media-session.service
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire pipewire-pulse
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
sudo apt remove pipewire-audio-client-libraries pipewire
```

Comment: This actually helped me because when I tried these commands, I realized I never had pipewire-pulse installed. Installing that fixed it for me

Comment: Running `sudo apt remove pipewire` also attempted to remove `ubuntu-desktop` and other core functionality in Ubuntu 22.04, causing the login screen not to come up.

Comment: @mofojed aren’t you on 23.04 instead? Pipewire is the default since 22.10, you can’t remove it.

Comment: @DidierL Nope, I'm on 22.04. Not sure why it removes `ubuntu-desktop` as well.

Comment: I'd like to caution anyone against running this set of commands without reviewing everything they do. This removed ubuntu-desktop from my pc and I had to fix it all from the command line because the computer crashed on running these commands

Comment: As others have noted, these commands remove ubuntu desktop and some gnome packages leaving you with no desktop GUI.

Answer (score 5):

At least on Ubuntu 22.04, you can't auto start PulseAudio without disabling PipeWire-Pulse, I fixed the PulseAudio autostart by just running this one below.

```
systemctl --user mask pipewire-pulse.service pipewire-pulse.socket
```

Answer (score 2):

That ppa has a man-page error

To revert this ppa

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
```

And check you won't uninstall a lot of packages