# Weird volume sliders on startup

Tags: wireless, gnome, sound, pulseaudio, headset

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, I have a Razer Barracuda X headset working fine. The usb receiver is always connected, when I start my computer this weird thing displays:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8SNJ.jpg

if I run `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio` the GUI gets normal.
Headset still works fine, but this weird visual bug just tilts me. How can I solve?

**EDIT:** seems to be solved by following: [How to uninstall pipewire and go back to pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407885/how-to-uninstall-pipewire-and-go-back-to-pulseaudio) and removing the pipewire ppa

Comment: Bugs are off topic here. :(

Comment: @user68186 where can I post?

Comment: What does the GUI normally look like for comparison (I use a custom theme with xfce4 notifications)?

Comment: @mchid it should be like this: https://imgur.com/a/J0K97Hs

Comment: It looks like it's possibly showing a right and left volume slider instead of a single integrated volume. Although, I guess it could be the volume for more than one device. Have you tried testing this by reducing the volume of one of the sliders when two are shown to see what happens?

Comment: See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: @mchid it seems to me like one is for the volume and one is for the microphone, but moving both of them makes nothing happen, they are just useless, GUI totally bugged. However, it seems to be fixed now and I edited my answer, it was probably some conflict between pulseaudio and pulsewire, which I had installed.

Comment: Okay. I voted to close this as a duplicate of [How to uninstall pipewire and go back to pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407885/how-to-uninstall-pipewire-and-go-back-to-pulseaudio)