sound support missing after upgrading to 24.04
I have upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04. Since that, there is no sound through the HDMI cable on my TV. Am I missing some driver?

Hi Apologies - I cannot code but I think some GUI's might help.
What does Alsamixer look like?
Is anything disabled? Do you have Pulse / Pulsemixer installed so you can see what / where inputs are going.

I believe PipeWire is now the default and not PulseAudio. So it could be to do with that. See here for some info and GUIs for PipeWire: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire I don't know if there is an official guide to changing from PipeWire back to PulseAudio but I found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407885/how-to-uninstall-pipewire-and-go-back-to-pulseaudio but be careful as removing pipewire package can apparently remove other packages and break systems.
